# Chrome localhost does not work

Tags: google-chrome, localhost

I have changed my hostname as "wp.dev"

[host image that I change my host address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcYXZ.png)
But when I type wp.dev on the address bar, and press enter then I show an issue like as screenshot. please help me.
[chrom issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6xjT.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have removed localhost from `/etc/hosts`, don't do that, instead just add whatever additional name you need at the end of the line.

So have:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost wp.dev
```

It's important for your system to have "localhost" resolve correctly (whether this is needed in `/etc/hosts` I don't know, but I'd assume it should be left in place).

Secondly, don't use `.dev` anymore.  It's now been registered as an official TLD on the internet, so there is now the potential for name clashes between local and external sites.  Using `localdomain` is an option, or using some domain you own is another (even if just using it locally and not serving it from any DNS server, it'll still avoid collisions).

The error message you're actually getting in Chrome doesn't seem to be related to the above problems.  Instead it looks like there isn't a web server responding at that address.  To verify check it by typing 127.0.0.1 into Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for your positive response. But in this situation, it works in Mozilla Firefox. When I save with localhost, the CSS file doesn't load.